# Image not showing in the webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP.NET app which has a master page.

The app logo is specified in the master page:

```
<img src="Images/a.jpg" alt="Logo Image" id="companylogo" />
```

And I have bunch of content pages. This logo is shown in all of these without any problem.

Then I have Registration folder, which contains Reg.aspx. So unlike other files reg.aspx is in a folder and not in the same level of the master file.

The master file logo does not show up if user navigates to this reg page.

I tried

```
<img src="~/Images/a.jpg" alt="Logo Image" id="companylogo" />
```

But this does not work either.

Comment: if your Images folder is in the web root, drop the ~ and just use `/Images/a.jpg`

Comment: @hairraisin Doing that would break your site if you deploy it as a virtual application and the image is in the virtual application, not the parent site. It's better to make links relative to the application root rather than the site root, in case they're different.

Comment: @hair raisin Tried that and it did not word.

Comment: @tnw: yes that was the trick. Thanks. Put this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `runat="server"` when you're using the tilde in the src path.